# How to print array without white spaces after comma

Tags: arrays, swift

I need the output of my print(array) command not to have a space after the comma.

looks like Swift inserts a white space between the comma and the next element by default, but i need the output without these white spaces because output needs to match the one in HackerRank

'''

```
let array = [1,2,3,4]
print(array)
```

'''

i need the result to be: [1,2,3,4]
but instead it's: [1, 2, 3, 4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4]
print(array.debugDescription.replacingOccurrences(of: ", ", with: ","))
```

Output:

> [1,2,3,4]